# flutter could not find com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode when using flutter_barcode_scanner

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode, barcode-scanner, vision

I have this error when using flutter_barcode_scanner  :

Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode not found.
Error loading optional module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode not found.
D/ViewRootImpl@9677bb1BarcodeCaptureActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0

could any one  help me please!

how to reproduce :
1- I just run the example provided with package
2- select scan barcode
3- the app ask for permission -> accept giving the permission
4- the scanner keep scan and did not catch the barcode
5- the error appear in android  studio in the run tab

main.dart

```
  import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _scanBarcode = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
            '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)!
        .listen((barcode) => print(barcode));
  }

  Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Barcode scan')),
            body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Flex(
                      direction: Axis.vertical,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => scanBarcodeNormal(),
                            child: Text('Start barcode scan')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => scanQR(),
                            child: Text('Start QR scan')),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => startBarcodeScanStream(),
                            child: Text('Start barcode scan stream')),
                        Text('Scan result : $_scanBarcode\n',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                      ]));
            })));
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code (even though it is provided with the package).  It will make it easier for SO users to help.

Comment: ok , I will provide it

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added these permissions in your app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application ...>
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem
Try to run on another mobile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32928099)